# How do I correct this class extension in Java?

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to make  program that has a Person class with one field : name(String) and accessor and mutator. and then make a second class Student ( extends Person class) - one field: id and accessor and mutator of id. then to test it make an object and assign name and id and print out result.

This is what I have so far:

Person Class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Person {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private String name;

    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName(String n)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Student class //I think this is the class with the extension:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person;


public class Student extends Person {

    public int idNumber;

    Student(String name, int idNumber) {

    }

    public void setID(int id)
    {
        idNumber = id;
    }

    public int getID(int id)
    {
        return idNumber;
    }

}
```

and then the main class to test the result:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class MainStudentID {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Students name: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Students ID Number:");
        int idNumber = keyboard.nextInt();


        Student Student = new Student(name, idNumber);

        System.out.println("Your name is: " + Student.person.getName());
        System.out.println("Your id Number is: " + Student.Student.getID());




    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, and I apologize for my crappy code, first time learning about the topic of class extensions.

Comment: Your `getXXX()` methods don't need to have parameters. You aren't even using them!

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting errors on the print out. "run:
Enter Students name: 
Ryan Smith
Enter Students ID Number:
4555321
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at person.MainStudentID.main(MainStudentID.java:29)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)"

Comment: @user1819827 - see my update, the problem is more clear now thanks to your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the values of name and id in your Student constructor. You're not storing them which is why you're not getting a result when you try to print.

You also need to get rid of the parameters in your get methods.

Person Class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Person {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private String name;

    public Person(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Student class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package person;


public class Student extends Person {

    public int idNumber;

    Student(String name, int idNumber) {
        super(name);
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public void setID(int id)
    {
        idNumber = id;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: `name` has private access and can not be reference from `Student` ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it gets very confusing looking at extensions the first time around and thank you especially @TylerFerraro for providing a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a constructor on you `Person` class that took the name...

```
public class Person {
    //...
    public Person(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }
    //...
}
```

This will force you to supply the name to the `Person` when you create a `Student`

```
public class Student extends Person {
    //...
    public Student(String name, int idNumber) {
        super(name);
        setID(idNumber);
    }
    //...
}
```

Mind you, I'd probably also create a person and student interface that provided the basic functionality required by the implementation, but that's probably overkill for the question

As has already begin pointed out, your getters don't need parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments describe

```
person.MainStudentID.main(MainStudentID.java:29)
```

This means you have another class that's somehow being involved in this one.  This error is NOT coming from the code in your example!

You've got a class called `MainStudentID.java` that's being accessed and causing this error.

My guess is, when you say `extends Person`, you've imported the `MainStudentID` class instead of the class in your sample code.

Make sure the addresses of your package imports at the top of the file are the ones you want.

---

*Other issues*

Everything looks OK on first glance, except that you haven't set IDs or names for your new `Student`.

Call the `setID` and `setName` methods after you get the input, and things should work better.

Another option is to initialize them (set them to something right when they're declared) and you'll see that they haven't been changed yet.

Also, as @Bernard pointed out, in your `getXXX` methods, you don't need a parameter - their sole purpose is to return a field.  They don't work with any other information.

Comment: so you mean calling them like 'code' Student.setName(); 'code' and 'code' Person.setID 'code' @Steve?

Comment: Yes, except pass the `name` field: `Student.setName(name)`  The `setName` method is expecting a new name, it's saying "OK great, I'll set it, just tell me what to set it to".  Same for the ID.